# Sending sensitive data between a android app and a pc application via bluetooth

Tags: java, android, security, bluetooth

I have to send sensitive data between android app and a java application via bluetooth. I still have a few questions about the implementation. The app will not be published in Google Play.

- Is the Bluetooth encryption sufficient to guarantee the security of
  my data?
- Should I also encrypt the data on the application layer?

  - Whats a good practice to do the key exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth uses [E0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E0_%28cipher%29) for encryption, which gets broken a bit more every year since 1999 (in published papers, and probably even more otherwhere...) and [ECDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman) for key agreement, which is vulnerable by design to some things like man-in-the-middle-attacks.
Additionally, older bluetooth devices may use no encryption at all, the whole protocol has some more design flaws, and there are ready-to-use exploit kits around.

In 2007, someone made an [overview](http://gsyc.es/~anto/ubicuos2/bluetooth_security_and_hacks.pdf) over some other known problems; I didn´t read it but maybe it interests you (but keep in mind that was 8 years ago. Today, the situation is worse.)

So, depending on what you´re exactly doing and how secure it should be, you might want to do everything by yourself. As you´re just talking about encryption, you should think first what exactly you want to protect against. Encryption will prevent that someone reads the transmitted data, but it won´t prevent eg. some "evil" device making you believe that it is the real receiver (in short, authentication).

For encryption itself, AES is ok. The key exchange is a problem if both deviced have nothing to start with ... if you could deploy (asymmetric) keys for some auth. stuff and use them as help to generate a AES session key, it would help very much (together with authentication, you could use eg. ECDH without MITM problems)